# vagrant + phansible - failed to fetch PPA information

Tags: php, vagrant, ansible

After setting up my configuration with phansible, and executing  `vagrant up`

the provisioning process finishes with:

```
--
==> default: TASK [php : Add ppa Repository] ************************************************
==> default: fatal: [192.168.33.99]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "failed to fetch PPA information, error was: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"}
--
```

Any suggestions on how I could get this working?

Thanks in advance!

--

provisioning script:

```
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: [git, imagemagick]
    timezone: Europe/Madrid
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
vagrant_local:
    install: '1'
    vm: { base_box: trusty64, hostname: default, ip: 192.168.56.101, memory: '4096', sharedfolder: ./, useVagrantCloud: '1', syncType: nfs }
apache:
    install: '1'
    docroot: /vagrant/application/htdocs/public
    servername: www.myservername.com
mysql:
    install: '1'
    root_password: mypwd
    database: mydb
    user: 
    password:
    dump:
php:
    install: '1'
    ppa: php5-5.6
    packages: [php5-cli, php5-intl, php5-mcrypt, php5-curl, php5-gd, php5-mysql, php5-xdebug, php5-dev]
```

Comment: without your provisioning script in the question, its impossible to tell you whats wrong -

Comment: provisioning script added, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with

```
php:
    install: '1'
    ppa: php5-5.6
    packages: [php5-cli, php5-intl, php5-mcrypt, php5-curl, php5-gd, php5-mysql, php5-xdebug, php5-dev]
```

so it tries to add `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` which does not exist anymore, it has been migrated. (see https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

so you can change to

```
php:
    install: '1'
    ppa: php
```

so it will add the correct ppa - If you want to work with php 5.6 version make sure to add this version in your packages

```
php:
    install: '1'
    ppa: php
    packages: [php5.6-cli, php5.6-intl, php5.6-mcrypt, php5.6-curl, php5.6-gd, php5.6-mysql, php5.6-xdebug, php5.6-dev]
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is looking at a deprecated PPA for php.

As @Frédéric Henri wrote, it's hard to help you without any details. May be  [Failed to fetch PPA information (PHP 5.6 / Ubuntu 12.04)](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/971) helps.